# Warning when awaitable calls aren't waited/awaited

Tags: c#, async-await

This code causes exceptions to get lost.

Instead of `boo.DoStuff()`, it should be `Task.WaitAll(bar.DoStuff())`.

It's perfectly safe to block because the timer callback is already on a thread pool thread, and I'm not doing anything that would use IOCP. If I don't block, I silently lose any exceptions.

How can I get either VS/ReSharper/something to give me a warning on this line?

```
public class Foo
{
    readonly IBoo _boo;
    readonly Timer _timer;

    public Foo(IBoo boo)
    {
        _boo = boo;
        _timer = new Timer(Beat, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }

    void Beat(object state)
    {
        _boo.DoStuff();  // <-- warning wanted here
        // Task.WaitAll(bar.DoStuff());   <-- what I should have written
    }
}

public interface IBoo
{
    Task DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: `WaitAll` does not await a task, it blocks code execution. Those are VERY different behaviors. Which are you wanting to do, make Bar an awaitable call or make Bar a blocking call?

Comment: Make sure the implementation of `DoStuff()` is marked `async`. That might be why you aren't seeing CS4014, that warning has to do with `async` and `await`, which it doesn't appear that you're using.

Comment: @SpikeX you don't mark a function `async` in the interface. To see CS4014 `Bar` would need to be the one marked async.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh, well the asker didn't show the implementation. Edited my comment.

Comment: Hi everyone, I've just updated the question to better show my full scenario.

Comment: SpikeX had it *almost* right: as soon as you mark your `void Beat` as `async`, any non-awaited async calls (such as `_boo.DoStuff`) will produce a warning.

Comment: But then I just have an async void, which still swallows it. And, that still requires me to remember to do something. For the code above, as posted, I want a tool to recognise that this is wrong.

Comment: Can you define what is wrong in the first place? There *are* things like fire-and-forget tasks where you don't care for the return value of a task.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a tool to provide this warning but Resharper is extensible. They recently open-sourced the code for an extension that marks all allocations in the source code. It seems to be not that hard to write an extension. It would trigger on all method calls that return `Task` and do not immediately use the result of the call in any way.

You might face false positives, though, in cases where a method returns a task that is polled for error information elsewhere. Still, this is a useful warning. I often see questions on Stack Overflow that would be solved by not ignoring some task.

Comment: This looks more like a Comment rather than an Answer.

Comment: @FilipEkberg I think a custom R# extension is all he can hope for at the moment. For that reason I made it an answer.